# Connecting To Projector in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vga, projector

I tried to connect My new ubuntu version with a projector.But it was useless cause Laptop not identified that projector.Updated my Nvidia Driver also.I installed disper also.but couldn't connect to it.Any solutions??

Comment: Did you try "function key" + "The icon having two monitors on it"? Mine is F3.

Comment: Yes Tried.Not working :(

Comment: have same problem with nvidia card

Comment: type command 'xrandr' in a terminal; post output

Comment: Try steps here:
http://askubuntu.com/a/170999/38845

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. 12.04 is EOL. Question has no answers. VTC as `not reproducible`