# Error While Creating New Resolution Mode

Tags: screen, display-resolution

I was trying to create a new resolution for my second monitor following this steps:

[Can't set a higher screen resolution in a external display in a Dell Mini 10v laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73007/cant-set-a-higher-screen-resolution-in-a-external-display-in-a-dell-mini-10v-la)

but i got this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

when i ran this code:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

how do i move forward?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I just needed to rename the newmode.