# Unable to set my screen resolution higher

Tags: display, display-resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS on this system

> **Processor:** Intel Core i5-7400
>
> **Mainboard:** H110M-Gaming3-CF

The problem is the highest resolution it can go up to is 1024x768, which is terrible. How can I set my resolution to a higher resolution (i.e. FHD which fits my screen)? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your post and show `sudo lshw -C display`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Ubuntu or the other versions of it like (k,l,x,edu,etc.,) are required to add the resolution we want to set on some monitors.

So follow my steps:-

1. Open a Terminal by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `xrandr` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. Note the display name usually **VGA-1** or **HDMI-1** or **DP-1**
4. Type `cvt 1920 1080` *(to get the `--newmode` args for the next step)* and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
5. Type `sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
6. Type `sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1080_60.00"` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *(replace **VGA-1** with your display type (step 3) like **HDMI-1** or **DP-1**)*
7. Now close the terminal and go to *Settings >> Display settings* and change it to *1920x1080*
8. Enjoy FHD.

To make the above settings stick when you restart your computer, do the following.

**For integrated displays**

- goto your terminal and type `vim ~/.profile` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Paste in the shell command from step 5 and 6, then save.

**For external displays**

- create a script called **external_monitor_resolution.sh** in the directory **/etc/profile.d/**. using `sudo vim /etc/profile.d/external_monitor_resol.sh`.
- Paste in the shell command from step 5 and 6, then save.

*(**Note:** if using `sudo` would require you typing a password, your system might freeze on startup while waiting for you to input a password. So when pasting **do away with the `sudo`**)*
Something like this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1080_60.00"`
```

and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *(replace **VGA-1** with your display type (step 3) like **HDMI-1** or **DP-1**)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's DP-1, I had been trying VGA-1 like forever

Comment: Yeah nice to hear it's fixed but did you restarted and checked that the resolution was there?

Comment: My screen went to FHD right after the last command, no restart or Setting > Display needed.

Comment: No, what i'm asking is that if i restarted my pc which is VGA the resolution change changesback to 1024x768. That's what i told you to check. By the way how did you respond so fast? I can get notifications only if i get to this site.

Comment: I'll check that later. I'm browsing StackOverFlow atm, noti goes there too.

Comment: Oh if you don't want that to happen just goto Terminal and type gedit ~/.profile and add the lines from step 4 and 5 line by line. Peace!

Comment: I tried, do I need to add anything except those 2 lines. .profile saved but it went back to 1027x768 the next time.

Comment: it should reload when you log in, I had the same problem after my HD screen broke, and I replaced it with a low res monitor.  the problem you might get is that youll get multiple listings in xrandr for the same monitor, and then running this script will produce an error where the device has eDP-1 (or whatever) already. the file you want to add a function to is ".bashrc"  but perhaps a better solution would be to make xrandr mods permanent. https://askubuntu.com/questions/63681/how-can-i-make-xrandr-customization-permanent

Comment: Well this worked for me 
`cvt 1920 1080
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"`

Comment: Having the same problem on my laptop. Unfortunately, adding the three lines above (like e.g. TriNguyen in comment above) resulted in ubuntu not loading at all: no loading screen, just black. I had to type ctrl-alt-F2 and log in via terminal, change the .profile back, and then it worked. It is just very strange and frustrating that ubuntu does not add the res. choices in settings. Any new information into fixing this problem, or is making xrandr mods permanent like in the above comment the best one?

Comment: Instead of going to Settings >> Display (in my case, with kubuntu, I did not have the new mode) you can type `xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00`

Comment: That worked for me, but how can I make this take effect on the login screen and all the other's user profiles too?

Comment: Could you explain what these commands are doing please? Thanks!

Comment: This solved my issue! Thanks! Based on that, I built a simple bash script to automate the fix:

----------
#!/bin/bash
DEVICE=$1
if [ "$1" == "" ] ; then 
    DEVICE="DP-1"  
fi
MODELINE=\"$(cvt 1920 1080 | grep -e "^#" -v | cut -d '"' -f 2-)
MODENAME=$(echo $MODELINE | cut -d " " -f 1)
MODEPARAMS=$(echo $MODELINE | cut -d " " -f 2-)
sudo xrandr --newmode $MODENAME $MODEPARAMS
sudo xrandr --addmode $DEVICE $MODENAME
----------

Enjoy!

Comment: Sir, you're a master. I'm deeply grateful.

Comment: Actually, sudo wasn't even needed when running the command as a regular user for me. As soon as I executed the addmode command, the resolution automatically corrected onscreen.

Comment: I got this error as soon as I tried `xrandr --addmode ...` , here it is: `X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)`

Comment: I had to switch from the prorietary Nvidia drivers to the Nouveau drivers in the "Software & Updates" app (Additional Drivers tab).

Answer (score 3):

Answer from @ARTube perfect and guys who are facing the problem after editing .profile please follow the comment from Christopher.L

Then add the 5th and 6th line to your `.profile` without `sudo` command and save then restart it will work fine.

eg:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Answer (score 3):

A **better way** than creating a script would be to configure X properly.

1. Reboot in recovery mode
2. **Create** a new **xorg.conf** file `Xorg -configure`
3. **Reboot** in graphical mode.
4. From a terminal, generate the proper settings for your desired resolution using **gtf** command `gtf 1600 1200 60`.
5. **Copy the output** and using your favorite editor add it to the section **Monitor** of the file we create step 2 Ex: `sudo vi /root/xorg.conf.new`
6. **Move the file to /etc/X11** folder `sudo mv /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
7. **Reboot**.

And that's it should now be able see your new resolution in your **display settings**.

The full procedure is described [here](https://www.overwriteit.com/linux-resolution-stuck-at-1024x768-solution/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @AbdulR's solution, I built a simple script that may be useful to automate the creation of the new mode (I named it **"fixvga.sh"**):

```
#!/bin/bash
DEVICE=$1
if [ "$1" == "" ] ; then 
    DEVICE="DP-1"  
fi
MODELINE=\"$(cvt 1920 1080 | grep -e "^#" -v | cut -d '"' -f 2-)
MODENAME=$(echo $MODELINE | cut -d " " -f 1)
MODEPARAMS=$(echo $MODELINE | cut -d " " -f 2-)
sudo xrandr --newmode $MODENAME $MODEPARAMS
sudo xrandr --addmode $DEVICE $MODENAME
```

Then, from the terminal, simply type:

```
./fixvga.sh VGA-1
```

Remember to replace "VGA-1" with the display you want to fix (in my case, "DP-1", which I made the default). After that, on Display Settings, you may be able to choose the 1920x1080 resolution on your display (as long as it supports it).

Enjoy!