# Gnome fractional scaling below 100%

Tags: display, ubuntu-gnome, 19.10, scaling

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on an old laptop with max resolution of 1366x768.

Is there a way to scale down gnome below 100%?
I have already set text scaling to .90 and reduced the dock icon size to 36.

Is this feature available in other window managers?

Comment: I havent tried it, for text scaling only.  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1018/text-scaler/

Comment: You are welcome https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075157/unable-to-set-my-screen-resolution-higher

Answer (score 4):

try with `xrandr --output HDMI --scale 0.75x0.75` being HDMI your output from the list  `xrandr --listmonitors` and 0.75 the wanted factor.

Comment: It makes everything blurry. However if I do the same on Unity Desktop (which supports doing this through a GUI), the scaling works perfectly.

Comment: this is corecct:  `xrandr --output HDMI --scale 1.2x1.2`

Comment: @ArMo372 is right the factor has to be more than 1 to generate scale below 100%

Comment: **displays are overlapping?** => solution is apparently to set an offset and auto adjust e.g. for 2 displays/monitors (ltr) left display has original resolution 1920x1080 => 1920x1,2 => **2304**: "Left display": `xrandr --output DP-1-2 --scale 1.2x1.2 --auto --pos 0x0`, "Right display": `xrandr --output DP-1-3 --scale 1.2x1.2 --auto --pos 2304x0`

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Debian 11. I tested this in RockyLinux - which is a CentOS splinter - and it worked.

At a terminal prompt enter:

```
xrandr --listmonitors
```

The output will look something like this:

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*LVDS-1 3620/309x2036/174+0+0  LVDS-1
```

In the output the end bit is your video output. In my case it's "`LVDS-1`"

In a terminal enter:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/.desktop
```

Enter the below bit of info changing the `LVDS-1` to what ever the output was from your system.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=xrandr
Exec=xrandr --output LVDS-1 --scale 2.65x2.65
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
```

Reboot your system and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug for this on the Gnome launchpad site, I hope a few more people will go over there and raise it's profile:-

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1724037

Answer (score 0):

I found this while going through the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1724037) of the bug issue provided by James Lewis above.

> Apparently it was partially implemented in GNOME 42 (Ubuntu 22.04):
> https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/commit/bfb7151c
>
> 1. Enable fractional scaling in Settings and set it to 100%.
> 2. Edit ~/.config/monitors.xml and change the scale value to 0.5
> 3. Log in again.

This has worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, GNOME 42.9.

My primary display is set at 100% and secondary monitor at 80% now.

Thank you Lewis!