# Scaling Issue on Secondary Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, external-monitor

So I have a 16-inch built-in laptop display with scale 100% in the display settings on Ubuntu. I also have a 22-inch secondary Acer monitor. The problem is not only that things appear way bigger than they should be on my secondary monitor, but that I am also unable to move my mouse cursor from my laptop display to my secondary monitor through the bottom of the screen. [Here's what it looks like in the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ktgO.png)

I figured that if I could lower the scale of my secondary monitor, I can easily fix this issue, but unfortunately Ubuntu lacks this functionality.

I should also mention that I tried the approach with xrandr here, and it didn't work: [Gnome fractional scaling below 100%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199655/gnome-fractional-scaling-below-100)

Is there any way to lower the scale on my secondary monitor lower than 100% or fix my issue in another way somehow?