# Resolution dropped from 1600*1200 to 1024*768 after updating from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: graphics, 19.04, 19.10, display-resolution

I was using Ubuntu 19.04 and everything was fine. yesterday I updated to 19.10. There was no problem after rebooting. Today for some reason after I booted my computer, the resolution dropped from 1600*1200 to 1024*768. I tried restarting it again but it is still the same. 1024*768 is the highest resolution in the display settings now. I tried to add the 1600*1200 again manually [using these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075157/unable-to-set-my-screen-resolution-higher)
but the image was shifted to the left and slightly up. I could barely see the dock and the top bar because of that. And of course there were black margins on the right and the bottom.
Here is the output from `inxi -Fz` for the system specs

```
System:
  Host: ahmed-pc Kernel: 5.3.0-51-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.34.3 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ProDesk 600 G1 TWR 
  v: N/A serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 18E7 serial: <filter> BIOS: Hewlett-Packard 
  v: L01 v02.75 date: 05/04/2018 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-4590 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
  Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/3700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 885 2: 967 
  3: 935 4: 871 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics 
  driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: AMD Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770] driver: radeon v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: radeon resolution: 1024x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD JUNIPER (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.3.0-51-generic LLVM 9.0.0) 
  v: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-3: AMD Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series] 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-51-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I217-LM driver: e1000e 
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter type: USB 
  driver: rtl8192cu 
  IF: wlxa0f3c11aff07 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.58 TiB used: 41.50 GiB (2.6%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST3500414CS size: 465.76 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Samsung model: HD105SI size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Crucial model: CT240BX500SSD1 size: 223.57 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 105.23 GiB used: 41.50 GiB (39.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc3 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C gpu: radeon temp: 53 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 324 Uptime: 3m Memory: 11.59 GiB used: 3.92 GiB (33.8%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.36
```

Comment: Perhaps replace your `inxi -F` output by `inxi -Fz`. The -z option removes some more personal information like IP addresses and hardware addresses.

Comment: It looks you are running on Wayland. As a first possibility, try switching to Xorg (which Ubuntu still is using by default in a fresh install. This is an AMD card, currently you seem to be using a kernel driver. Is there a proprietary driver for this model?

Comment: Yes I replaced it with `inxi -Fz`. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I tried to look for some driver for this version of AMD and for intel but I think the problem is because something went wrong while upgrading. When I use `sudo apt-get update`, I get The repository 'http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.` The driver for intel needs this command to run as I found. I also can not add a new repository.
By the way I used Wayland after this problem occurred to see if it also happens with it.