# Ubuntu 20.04 how to set screen resolution to 1080p with integrated Intel UHD graphics 630

Tags: 20.04, graphics, display, display-resolution

My gpu recently died, but that's no big deal because I have Intel integrated graphics UHD 630. It gives me output straight from my motherboard. Great! Right? Well... here's where things get tricky. I'm getting the display to work, but it's stuck at 1024x768(4:3) resolution and my AOC G2460PG 24" Gaming Monitor has 1920x1080(16:9) native resolution. So my screen looks like a tiny screen inside of a big monitor. I've been trying to figure out how to fix this and I came across this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075157/unable-to-set-my-screen-resolution-higher) which gave me hope because I actually was able to get 1920x1080 as an option in my display settings, but as soon as I click apply the screen goes black than the "do you want to keep these settings message" expires because I can't see the message to click apply and keep the changes. After the screen reverts to the the 1024x768 resolution. Now I'm stuck and hoping someone can help with this... otherwise I'm forced to keep my tiny screen resolution since it's impossible to get a new GPU for a reasonable price right now anyway.

Here are the steps I took so far:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync


sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

sudo xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Comment: You want the `cvtmode` and `addmode` commands I think but  on my phone.

Comment: yes, that's what I did ```cvt 1920 1080```.

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the full output of running `xrandr` as well as all the commands and outputs you get when doing your `cvt` and `xrandr --addmode` etc. How is your monitor connected to your PC HDMI? DP?

Comment: @codlord I added the steps.

Comment: @Alex DisplayPort (like HDMI) should communicate with the monitor and so the system should know exactly what resolutions/refresh rates the monitor/card supports. I have seen this exact same behaviour once with my own setup where I had a laptop with one monitor connected to HDMI and another connected to DP. The DP one only listed the 4 modes until I unplugged the HDMI when it would immediately started working correctly. I only "fixed" this by plugging and re-plugging both monitors several times! Have you tried unplugging/replugging both ends? Do you have any other HDMI/DP plugged in?

Comment: @codlord it's ok just reinstalled the OS. Everything is working fine now.