# Stuck booting to black screen after adding new xrandr mode

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, xrandr, .profile

One of my monitors is 2560x1440, 60Hz capable but my Ubuntu 20.04 was only allowing me to set the maximum display resolution to 1920x1080. I followed the instructions in this post [Unable to set my screen resolution higher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075157/unable-to-set-my-screen-resolution-higher) (solution by AbdulR). Part of this involved me adding a new xrandr mode by creating a new shell file within /etc/profile.d/. Following a reset to my computer I can make it to the log in screen, but once I input my password I am stuck on a black screen on both my integrated display and external monitors. How can I revert these changes to get my display back.

Comment: Boot from a Live Media and revert the changes you made.

Comment: I just learned about switching to virtual terminal at the logon screen via Ctrl+Alt+F2 (still a new ubuntu user lol). I was able to login here and remove the suspect profile.d shell, restart, and my issue was resolved.

Comment: Might be a good idea to make that an answer using the answer your own question option bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned about switching to virtual terminal at the logon screen via Ctrl+Alt+F2 (still a new ubuntu user). I was able to login here and remove the suspect profile.d shell, restart, and my issue was resolved.