# Unable to change the resolution of my built-in display

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, display-resolution

I can't change my built-in display's resolution under Settings -> Displays. I used to see a drop-down menu that allowed me to lower the resolution but it's gone since I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

However, I am able to change the resolution to 1920-1200 by running:

```
xrandr -s 1920x1200
```

The problem is that I usually connect my laptop to an external monitor and the above code does not work when that happens.

I would like to either:

1. figure out how to get back the dropdown menu with the alternative display resolutions
2. learn how to modify `xrandr -s 1920x1200` so that it works when the laptop is connected to an external monitor.

I have installed nvidia-520.

**xrandr output**

```
xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1600, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 215mm
   2560x1600     60.01*+ 165.02  
  1920x1200_60.00 (0x28d) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
```

**xrandr output when connected to an external monitor**

```
xandr -q

 Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1600, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-4 connected 2560x1600+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 16mm x 10mm
   2560x1600     60.01 + 165.02* 
  1920x1200_60.00 (0x28d) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
```

Comment: possible duplicate of
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075157/unable-to-set-my-screen-resolution-higher

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and in my case, it's drivers problem.

Step to fix:

1. Open **software and updates > additional drivers**
2. **changed driver to noveau and restarted** (If the problem is fixed, stay with it), or then
3. **Changed the driver back to the latest nvidia** and it prompted a few windows to setup an "enroll MOK" during boot to allow those specific 3rd party drivers to work. **Just followed the steps, rebooted**
4. During boot it prompted a few windows where **I just followed the steps, typed the password** I created on the previous step and that was it. It is working normally now.