# Change output resolution for RDT

Tags: display, display-resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, GNOME  42.9, Windowing X11 on a Optiplx 5060 on an old 1024x768 display using an DP to VGA adapter. I am connecting to it from a Windows PC via Windows remote desktop. One issue is that the screen resolution is defaulting to 1024x768 (no other choices on the Opti) and I'd like to change that to something closer to 1920x1080.

xrandr shows XWAYLAND0 rather than any type port. Strand thing, I think it was when I changed the starting res in RDT that xrandr came back with hdmi-2 so I followed the directions again from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075157/unable-to-set-my-screen-resolution-higher) #95, changing to 1280 x 960 and then that was an option back over in settings >display. It didn't actually work but after a restart xrandr when back to listing XWAYLAND0 which is not a valid port.

My goal is to run the Optiplex with Ubuntu headless.