# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS only one resolution available

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, display-resolution

I have an XPS13 with an Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS running on it. It has a Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 integrated graphical card. Everything was fine till the last reboot (before the reboot I have installed some Latex related packages). My display manager now shows only one resolution available:
[image]

Additionally, when I plug-in the external display nothing happens. Just before the reboot everything was working perfectly.

The output from xrandr looks as follows:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3200 x 1800, current 3200 x 1800, maximum 3200 x 1800
default connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3200x1800     90.00*
```

and from sudo lspci | grep -i vga

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
```

Does anyone knows any way to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I ran into a problem with some similaries to yours.
So the solution I used might help you. Source: [Can't set a higher screen resolution in a external display in a Dell Mini 10v laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73007/cant-set-a-higher-screen-resolution-in-a-external-display-in-a-dell-mini-10v-la).
In the terminal I did the following to add a new resolution of 1920 x 1200:

```
cvt 1920 1200
```

Assuming output is: "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
Replace that output in the two lines below with your output of cvt:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1200_60.00
```

In case this would help you, you could add a file .xprofile to your home directory with both xandr lines.

Answer (score 0):

it's frustating when youre in serious development deadline and suddenly shit like these happen. Please try running commands from
steps:

1. sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
2. sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
3. sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
4. sudo dpkg --configure -a
5. sudo apt clean
6. sudo apt update --fix-missing
7. sudo apt install -f
8. sudo dpkg --configure -a
9. sudo apt upgrade
10. sudo apt dist-upgrade
11. sudo reboot

source: https://ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/

Comment: Hi, please add the major steps to execute in the answer too. In case remote link going off-line for any reason. Thank you.